# Too many connections to server

Tags: posts, uploads, media, server

I'm facing a really weird problem with my wordpress/server.

Sometimes when I add media (images) to a new post, and then try to submit this post, instead of my website I got the information in browser:

```
connection rejected by server
```

I contacted my hosting provider to solve this problem and they claim that my wordpress is generating too many simultaneous connections to server and that's why my IP is being blocked (usually for about 48 hours). For everyone else the site is working perfectly fine.

Is it possible that adding images/submitting the post is generating more than 18 connections to server (that's the limit that my hosting provider has on its servers)?

And if yes, how to solve this problem?

I'm using wordpress always updated to the newest version.

Comment: Is this PHP 5.3? http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/23968

Comment: Nope. 5.2. I can set also php 5.4 or php dev

Comment: For the record, I run a number of sites on PHP 5.3 and don't have this issue. It would help if you could post the logs showing exactly what those connects are. Also, are you running any plugins? And if so have you tried disabling them?

Comment: once I will be able to reach my site I will post some logs. Yes, I tried disabling plugins

Comment: Do you mean web hosting provider? ISP (internet servvice provider) is typically company that provides you with access to Internet. If they give you hosting with weird restrictions - I'd look to change to _real_ hosting. :)

Comment: @Rarst - yeah, I meant my hosting provider. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: Try looking up setting for number of connections to server in your browser. Or, you know, nagging your hosting into removing stupid restriction. I am thinkings this probably can't really be handled on WordPress level.

Comment: I'm thinking the same, but needed to check it to start a fight with hosting provider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I contacted my hosting provider to solve this problem and they claim
>   that my wordpress is generating too many simultaneous connections to
>   server...

The only times I've seen hosts put limits on the number of MySQL connections is when the host is free or very cheap or incompetent.

Is it free hosting? It's really easiest to spend a little money and get a good host.

See [Recommended WordPress Web Hosting](http://wordpress.org/hosting/)

Comment: Nope, I use 1&1 hosting called "Unlimited" (hic!) http://www.1and1.com/

Comment: 1&1 is a problematic host. Their "Unlimited" package is far too cheap to be quality. Search the wordpress.org forums for opinions on them. And do a reverse DNS lookup on your IP to see how many other sites are on your server; that's another reason for an overloaded server.

Comment: Reverse DNS lookup shows me only one domain - serverklienta.pl (client server). Which is probably top-level domain for many, many clients...

Answer (score 0):

Many web hosting companies "throttle" accounts based on the number of simultaneous I/O connections & amount of CPU resources consumed. Your shared hosting should support around 10-20 simultaneous active users under this configuration for WordPress. Sounds like you were only using the site in development & triggered the account throttling, which may point to either problems in the WP install or overactive targeting by the web host. Check the error logs for the web site & consider another shared hosting plan with better resources.